# Does Spring Cloud AWS supports Amazon SNS message payload bigger than 256 using Amazon S3 Buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sns, payload

I am already using Spring Cloud AWS Messaging with SNS and SQS but I now I have a limitation because I am dealing with payloads bigger than 256kb.

I have done some research and I believe the answer to my question is NO but just checking to be sure...

Edit:
My concern was how to use payload offloading with Spring AWS Cloud where currently I am using NotificationMessagingTemplate class. For the workaround, I have added the following dependency
software.amazon.sns:sns-extended-client:1.0.0 which gave me access to SNSExtendedClientConfiguration and AmazonSNSExcentedeClient classes and I was able to send messages over 256kb doing payload offloading to an S3 bucket. I was also kind of confused with the AWS Java SDK due to springboot is still using version 1.X and an out of support one as far as I understand.

Comment: No the max is 256kb.  The library you reference just wraps the suggested way of handling this by copying a large message to S3 - it does not change the fact that 256kb is the limit.

Comment: @stdunbar I have just add an edit to my question

Answer (score 0):

The max size is 256 as specified in the docs here:

[Amazon SQS and SNS Announce 256KB Large Payloads](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/06/18/amazon-sqs-announces-256KB-large-payloads/#:%7E:text=Today%2C%20we%20are%20increasing%20the,to%20the%20existing%20JSON%20format)

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of confused here. So I can not send messages over 256kb via SNS? What about this doc here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/large-message-payloads.html

Comment: Not yet @smac2020, I am cloning the examples just to start testing. My second main concern was if I could still be using Spring Template out of the box for messaging and if it is just a matter of changing some Spring AWS cloud config

Comment: I also have not used that V1 SQS API. I am not sure if has been ported to V2. I will check and post back.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following dependency software.amazon.sns:sns-extended-client:1.0.0 which gave me access to SNSExtendedClientConfiguration and AmazonSNSExtendedClient classes and I was able to send messages over 256kb doing payload offloading to an S3 bucket

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.PublishRequest;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import software.amazon.sns.AmazonSNSExtendedClient;
import software.amazon.sns.SNSExtendedClientConfiguration;

@Component
public class SnsService {

    @Autowired
    AmazonSNS snsClient;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    AmazonS3 s3Client;

    public void sendLargePayloads(String topicName, String bucket, Object message, String subject) {

        final SNSExtendedClientConfiguration snsExtendedClientConfiguration = new SNSExtendedClientConfiguration()
                .withPayloadSupportEnabled(s3Client, bucket);
        final AmazonSNSExtendedClient snsExtendedClient = new AmazonSNSExtendedClient(snsClient,
                snsExtendedClientConfiguration);
        try {
            snsExtendedClient.publish(new PublishRequest().withTopicArn(topicName).withSubject(subject)
                    .withMessage(mapper.writeValueAsString(message)));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).